# Double IF does not work?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, conditional-statements

With this code I want to say

```
if %var% > 5 AND if %var% <10 THEN.
```

It works for 2 for instance it is "no" but for "11" the program ends and gets closed instead of following the "`else`" Can you help me solve this?

Code:

```bat
@echo off
:DEBUT
set /p "VAR=Type your text:"
if %VAR% geq 5 (
     if %VAR% leq 10 (
echo YEAH
goto DEBUT
  )
) else (
echo NO
goto DEBUT
)
```

Output:

```bat
Type your text:2
NO
Type your text:4
NO
Type your text:5
YEAH
Type your text:6
YEAH
Type your text:8
YEAH
Type your text:10
YEAH
Type your text:
```

Comment: post the code in the question, not an image

Comment: There is no applicable `else`. 11 gets picked up by `if %var% geq 5` but it doesn't hit `if %var% let 10` and there's no other code left to process so the script terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt at a rewrite.

```bat
@Echo Off
:DEBUT
Set/P "VAR=Type your text: "
If %VAR% GEq 5 If %VAR% LEq 10 Echo=YEAH
GoTo DEBUT
```

**Edit**

If you're looking to output YEAH or NO in every scenario, here's one method:

```bat
@Echo Off
:DEBUT
Set "_="
Set/P "VAR=Type your text: "
If %VAR% GEq 5 If %VAR% LEq 10 Set "_=T"
If Not Defined _ (Echo=NO) Else Echo=YEAH
GoTo DEBUT
```

and another:

```bat
@Echo Off
:DEBUT
Set/P "VAR=Type your text: "
If %VAR% GEq 5 (If %VAR% LEq 10 (Echo YEAH) Else Echo NO) Else Echo NO
GoTo DEBUT
```

Answer (score 0):

just to offer another alternative: No need for nested `if`s

```
:DEBUT
set "var=0"
Set/P "VAR=Type your text: "
If %VAR% lss 5 echo NO&goto :DEBUT
If %VAR% gtr 10 echo NO&goto :DEBUT
echo yes
goto :DEBUT
```

`set "var=0"` presets the variable to catch empty inputs (user just presses RETURN)